# Objective C - multiply blendmode

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have 2 UIImageViews layered one on top of another in the nib.
The bottom one just contains a picture, while the top one is a transparent png with gradient.
How can I apply "multiply" blend mode to the top image so it blend nicer with the bottom image?

Thanks,
Tee